# separate and display tags from DB

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to display blog posts' tags as separate words inside my HTML. I have written the code but it just display all tags without separating them. i also want that no tag should repeat. here is code

```
$query = "select tags FROM blog";
$q_result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($q_result) != 0)
{
   while($rr = mysql_fetch_row($q_result))
   {

?>
<li><a href="blog_l?tags=<?php echo $rr[0]; ?>"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i><?php echo $rr[0]; ?></a></li>
<?php }} ?>
```

here is a screenshot that what I got:

[image]

What I want is to separate each keyword. Take a look at the first line, it's coming from a single post (saleem, finance, poetry, testing); I want to make them separate and DISTINCT so that no keyword will be repeated.

Comment: what result you got?

Comment: At least I can help with avoiding dupes: use `select DISTINCT(tags) from blog`. The other thing is PHP which I'm not an expert in.

Comment: Try `select distinct tags FROM blog` if there are duplicates. What do you mean by `separating them`; on new lines, ordered, something else?

Comment: Show some tags in Blog tables plz!

Comment: @Vũ Tuấn Anh i have attached a screenshot and update question so you can better understand it.

Comment: @chris85 i have updated question with a screenshot

Comment: @A-2-A the column value is comma delimited.

Comment: @saleem You can explode on the comma with the returned comma value and then you will have a list of terms. It is unclear if you want the tags, unique to the row or the whole returned data set.

Comment: :( not fixed yet, will someone write complete code? as i am not getting all the things.

Comment: You need to clarify what you want.. For example in your list should `news` only be displayed once because it should be unique to the whole `tags` list or should each tag just be unique per row?

Comment: @chris85 all right, i need that no tag should not repeat at all. news should display only once. what i want is each tag should display on one row and it should not repeat. there is a tag "saleem" on row 1, 4 and 5. i want that it display only once.

Comment: Okay, can you post a text representation of your data so I don't have to transcribe it?

Comment: sorry i can't understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First suggestion :- `mysql_*` is deprecated library so use now `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

This will be the final code for you:-

```
<?php
$query = "select DISTINCT(tags) from blog"; // query to select unique tags
$q_result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$tag_data  = array(); // create an empty array
if(mysql_num_rows($q_result) != 0){
    while($rr = mysql_fetch_assoc($q_result)){ // fetch assoc instead of row
        $tag_data[] = $rr['tags']; // assign tags to new array
    }
}

foreach($tag_data as $tag){ // iterate through the tags array ?>
<li><a href="blog_l?tags=<?php echo $tag; ?>"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i><?php echo $tag; ?></a></li>
<?php }?>
```

**Note:- you can directly do the printing part of the value in while loop. Thanks.In my code `$tag_data` will be available for future use also.**

Comment: A write up of what you did and why would be useful. The `foreach` isn't needed.

Comment: It doesn't explain the logic. Why is a `foreach` being used as opposed to just outputting in the `while`.

Answer (score 1):

After get result from database query, use the bellow code to get array of tag as you wish

```
$dbResult = $rr[0]; //"news, demo text"
$arrayTag = array_unique(array_map('trim', explode(",",$dbResult))); //['news', 'demo text']
```